# No release file for Rethink db on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

I am installing Rethibk db on Ubuntu 18.04 using the instruction on their official site. However I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository &apos;http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt bionic Release&apos; does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can&apos;t be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

They don't have packages for Ubuntu 18.04 in their repository but only for 17.04 and earlier.

Ask them if they could provide a package for 18.04.

Alternatively you could try to manually download and install the package for 17.04 from http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pool/zesty/main/r/rethinkdb/ (I don't know if that works) or build from source as described on their web page.

Comment: I can confirm that version 2.3.6 fails during compilation on 18.04